# Does deleting a Facebook account in my iPhone Settings delete the actual Facebook account?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have a hand-me-down iPhone 4S from my wife running iOS 6.1.3. I have deleted the Facebook app. However other apps (like Instagram) still think my wife's Facebook account is linked to the phone and log in using her account.

In the iPhone's Settings app, there is still a Facebook subsection which lists my wife's account. There is a big red button to delete the account. This seems like the thing to do. But before I do, I want to confirm that doing so will only delete the account from this iPhone, NOT her actual Facebook account, which she naturally still wants to access from the web, her new phone, etc.

So -- safe to hit the big red button in this case?

Answer (score 6):

It only deletes from the phone. It will **not** delete the Facebook account from Facebook.